# Move to... > iCloud > Notes option is disabled

Tags: macos, icloud

I wanted to check that my notes are really backed up in the cloud but I've found this option disabled (see screenshot).

[image: iCloud Notes option is disabled]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the note was **already saved in the cloud** but you can't see the note in the iCloud folder on your local drive because **they are not saved as individual files**. Instead you can see it (and edit it) online at https://www.icloud.com/#notes3/ (caveat: you can't add images to a note there...)